# Error: The server does not support SSL connections Strapi

Tags: typescript, postgresql, strapi

I'm trying to deploy strapi with postgres, I tried several times to rewrite the config to roll back the pg version to version 7, nothing helps. what other ways are there to solve the problem?

```
  Error: The server does not support SSL connections                                                      

    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Progect\CMS\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:87:35)   
       at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:632:26)                                                          
       at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28)                                                                 
       at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)                                                                 
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:335:12)                                                 
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:308:9)                                          
       at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:245:10)                                            
      at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
```

datadase.ts

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  defaultConnection: "default",
  connection: {
    client: "postgres",
    connection: {
      connectionString: env("DATABASE_URL"),
      host: env("DATABASE_HOST", "localhost"),
      port: env.int("DATABASE_PORT", 5432),
      database: env("DATABASE_NAME", "postgres"),
      user: env("DATABASE_USER", "postgres"),
      password: env("DATABASE_PASSWORD", "12345"),
      schema: env("DATABASE_SCHEMA", "public"),
      ssl: env('DATABASE_SSL', false)
    },
  
  }
});
```

.env

```
HOST=0.0.0.0
PORT=1337
APP_KEYS=/CAc/WBKZ3TNThJWGnwYjA==,18u1UZYJzs2BtCKMgkNzTQ==,Z4mg+HeJTEb6hA4n3RzXRw==,rm/2i8al8Jfpz3ZR4B3ywg==
API_TOKEN_SALT=stGJgacmQuaeA7gtSRO+mQ==
ADMIN_JWT_SECRET=rE0UTdjnNqyYep5NbdT5jw==
TRANSFER_TOKEN_SALT=JiCFstDJYMFEl9D3hc91Hw==
# Database
DATABASE_CLIENT=postgres
DATABASE_HOST=127.0.0.1
DATABASE_PORT=5432
DATABASE_NAME=CMS
DATABASE_USERNAME=postgres
DATABASE_PASSWORD=12345
DATABASE_SSL=false
DATABASE_URL:     postgres://postgres:12345@host:5432/CMS?sslmode=disable
```

and I'm trying to deploy all this on a local machine

const path = require("path");

use the following config

This is one of the last

```
let pool = {
min: 0,
max: 10,
acquireTimeoutMillis: 600000,
createTimeoutMillis: 30000,
idleTimeoutMillis: 20000,
reapIntervalMillis: 20000,
createRetryIntervalMillis: 200,
>   };

let connection = {
connection: {
client: "postgres",
connection: {
host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
user: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
ssl: process.env.DATABASE_SSL
>       },
debug: false,
pool,
>     },
>   };



console.log(connection);

module.exports = ({ env }) => connection;
```

roll back the pg version to 7

Answer (score 0):

When you read environment variables from `process.env` their values are strings. This means that you are passing `ssl: "false"` in the config which is a truthy value so pg still tries to use SSL.

Try hardcoding `ssl: false` (an actual boolean value) in the config and see if that helps.

If you want ssl to be configurable using an environment variable consider using something like `ssl: process.env.DATABASE_SSL === "true"`. This way ssl will be enabled if the value of `DATABASE_URL` is `"true"` and disabled otherwise.

Comment: I tried to hard-code them, but I got even more errors.

Comment: at Parser.parseErrorMessage (C:\Users\user\Desktop\CMS\LightCMS\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:287:98)   
│       at Parser.handlePacket (C:\Users\user\Desktop\CMS\LightCMS\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)        
│       at Parser.parse (C:\Users\user\Desktop\CMS\LightCMS\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)